# python with open vs explicit open and close

Tags: python

I have a question regarding `with open` vs `f = open()` and `f.close()`.
I have been using `with open` for all.

What are the pro's and con's for each (excluding Python version)?
when's the appropriate scenario to use for each and why?

EDIT: I am asking this question because there seems to have NFS (prone to more stale NFS file handle error) errors with using 'with' over open/close

anyone have any insights on this as well?

Comment: It's too obvious. Using a context manager wins for a lot of reasons.

Comment: No real question in this question. Read: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager

Comment: @alKid its not obvious to me. could you elaborate?

Comment: @FilipMalczak i read it and does not answer my question

Comment: The context manager version will run `close` even if the `with` block is not finished due to an exception or a control flow statement such as `return`, `break`, or `continue`.

Comment: Here is a piece of code that shows the close() call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**with** is better.

From the docs on file.close(): http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.close

> As of Python 2.5, you can avoid having to call this method explicitly if you use the with statement. For example, the following code will automatically close f when the with block is exited:

```
from __future__ import with_statement # This isn't required in Python 2.6

with open("hello.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print line,
```

> In older versions of Python, you would have needed to do this to get the same effect:

```
f = open("hello.txt")
try:
    for line in f:
        print line,
finally:
    f.close()
```

Comment: when using 'with', does close happen at function exit or garbage collection time?

Comment: The file is closed after the with statement and becomes eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 5):

The *only* reasonable alternative to `with` statement is to use a construct like

```
 f = open(...)
 try:
     # do stuff with f
 finally:
     f.close()
```

And the with statement was added precisely to add syntax for this common pattern.  So, it's a no-brainer.

Comment: when using 'with', does close happen at function exit or garbage collection time?

Comment: Neither, it happens at the exit of the `with` block.  This is unrelated to GC.

Comment: strace doesnt support what you are telling me